# How to use Multiple runnable interfaces in single thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice

I am developing a java application which computes various mathematical functions.
Here is the scenario,
I have **M runnable tasks** (each for computing various problems, like one solves quadratic eqns, other solves exponential functions, something like that).
These **M runnables has to be executed for every N mins**. These runnables can be executed sequentially not necessarily in parallel manner.
I am **not allowed to create more than one thread**.

I can use ***ScheduledExecutorService*** for running the tasks periodically. As per Javadoc, Only one runnable can be used with ScheduledExecutorService.
There are methods like ***invokeAll(...)***, which allows us to provide Collection of runnable, but these doesnt provide scheduling option.

On browsing through internet I found, using ***Thread.sleep() is not a good way*** to develop an application.

Any suggestions??

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService` looks like a great fit to me, for the given use-case. Where in the docs does it say only one Runnable?

Comment: If you can only run one thing at a time and you need to schedule things, i think you could use a combination of quartz and jms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `ExecutorService` that contains only one thread to run your jobs:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

When you submit several jobs to this service using `invokeAll` method it will run them sequentially using single `Thread` instance.

If you want to use `ScheduledExecutorService` to run your jobs every N minutes you can switch to

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = 
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

that will provide you with additional methods to better control your jobs.

As you can see `invokeAll` method is derived from `ExecutorService`, so it does not provide you scheduling options. Still this is just a shortcut and you can schedule multiple `Runnable` instances using regular loop:

```
for (Runnable job : allJobs) {
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(job, 0L, N, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Comment: When you want them all to run at the same time sequentially, it seems a little strange to schedule them all individually. Why not just combine them into a single runnable like my answer?

Comment: Author should be able to choose what he likes better - this is why we have possibility to provide several answers. To your point - jobs will not run at the same time anyway, so it does not matter whether you run them within one scheduled job or using several jobs.

Comment: @Cruncher I think this is actually a cleaner and more flexible solution assuming it works properly.

Comment: This is the idea I had in mind. I have tested it and it works properly. It run each runnable interface sequentially after N minutes. I tried to find out how it schedules each runnable, but I couldn't. Can you explain the internal flow of the scheduler?? And Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Internally there is a queue of jobs with timestamps assigned. Each thread in executor's thread pool fetches job from queue if it is available (timestamp >= now), executes it, fetches next and so on. Executor service puts the same job into queue if it is periodic.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a multiple runnable class like the following, you can pass an instance of it to your scheduler and it will run all the runnables that you instantiated it with. The scheduler does the rest, this just sequentially runs the array of runnables.

```
public class MultipleRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private Runnable[] commands;
    public MultipleRunnable(Runnable[] commands)
    {
        this.commands = commands;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < commands.length ; i++)
        {
             commands[i].run();
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this to start it should work:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
new MultipleRunnable(new Runnable[]{run1, run2, ..., runM}),
n, n, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: I can create M Classes instead of runnable and call them sequentially, inside a single runnable interface. Then I need to schedule only one runnable using ScheduledExecutorService. It also does the work, for given scenario. Also, runnable interfaces are not used properly here. But I need to use multiple runnable interfaces for flexibility of the application. Anyways, Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @Adithyan How does this use Runnable interfaces improperly? Also, this class is rather abstract, it doesn't tell you how to define all of the runnables. By reading the question I had assumed that you already had your list of runnables. This just takes your group of runnables and wraps them into a single runnable that you can pass to anything that accepts a runnable.

Comment: @Adithyan You're right, that would work for the given scenario. But that solution would have to hard code it each time. This is a GENERAL solution for ANY group of Runnable Objects.